Can you have a value of null as an array index in C#?
While debugging a C# program I came across this line:
totals[null].AddTrip();
Can you have an array index of "null", and if so, what does it mean?

This feels like a bug. In some languages null actually represents the integer 0, which would make this valid. But even in that case totals[0] would be much better.

a [mre], which has the definition of totals  would be needed to answer.

I won't vote to reopen this post because, as Luuk says, it's missing crucial information: the precise data type of totals.

No, an array (typeof(Object[])) can not have an index of null. That would be a compile error.
However, in C#, other classes can use the indexer syntax [i]. Those classes could allow null as an index. What that means would depend on the implementation of the specific class.
